# Function is not only calling once

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to `execute only once`, but it is executing multiple times.

I am showing `alert` when user reaches the 90% of the page while scrolling. But it is showing the alert multiple times.

I have also tried:

- By turning statement to `true` after executed.

But it didn't work

File *page.html*

```
var percent = 90;
var window_scrolled;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    window_scrolled = ($(document).height()/100)*90;

    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= window_scrolled) {
        var excuted = false
        if (!excuted) {
            alert("scrolled to bottom");
            excuted = true
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are always setting the `excuted` to `false` each time, so it always runs.

Try this:

```
var excuted = false
$(window).scroll(function() {
    window_scrolled = ($(document).height()/100)*90;
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= window_scrolled) {
        if (!excuted) {
            alert("scrolled to bottom");
            excuted = true
        }
    }
});
```